# How to export/save a file to local drive

Tags: php, export

I have the results of a file created using PDO. I'm trying to save the results to a local file instead of a server location.
I've tried every example I could find on the internet but nothing seems to work. I don't know if it could be the way the application is implemented but it's not my application.

I've tried something simple but it still doesn't create the file.

```
$file = 'C:/people.txt';

$current = file_get_contents($file);

$current .= "John Smith\n";

file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

Comment: that code will only ever save to the server. You can't save directly to an end user's hard drive - think of the security implications if a website (like this one, for example) could just do whatever it wanted with your disk. You can offer a file for download, and the user can choose whether to download it or not. You need to send the correct headers, the correct mime type and the content that should comprise the downloadable file. You can google plenty of examples already for doing that in PHP.

Comment: Try `readfile` http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php